# (Probably Simple) Conditional PHP Loop

Tags: php

I've set up a database table like so:

```
table: group
id     name          subGroupOf
1      grandparent   NULL
2      parent           1
3      child            2
```

Here's what I'm trying to do in php:

When a user accesses a page, the page tells the auth() function they require 'child' permissions. Because 'child' is a subgroup of 'parent', members of both groups should get permission. But, parent is a subgroup of 'grandparent', so members of all three groups should have access.

Since there is no limit to how many subgroups could be nested, I knew I would need a loop. But I'm totally drawing a blank.

I know it needs to check if the group is a subGroupOf, and if so, validate the parent group. Here's what I have so far:

```
        // Get group of current user
        $group = mysqli_query($cxn,'SELECT group FROM user WHERE id='.$userID);

        // Compare group to permissions
        if($group == $permissions)
            return TRUE;

        // Check if group is a sub group
        $subGroupOf = mysqli_query($cxn,'SELECT subGroupOf FROM group WHERE id="'.$group.'"');
        if($subGroupOf == NULL)
        {
            // Wrong permissions
        }

        // Check if the parent group matches permissions
        if($subGroupOf == $permissions)
            return TRUE;
```

Somehow I need to loop that last part, and stop when it gets to

```
$subGroupOf == NULL
```

I'm fairly new to programming, so I'm still figuring out the logic...Any ideas? I don't need the whole thing written for me (that code is summarized anyways), I just need help figuring out the structure..

Comment: To clarify.  Say the group for the user is "child".  So you want the actual group loaded to be "grandparent", because "child" is a sub-group of "parent", and "parent" is a sub-group of "grandparent"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'loaded'. I want the script to compare the user's group, and any of that group's parent groups, to the group that the page says it requires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method, but you still need a function for recursion:

1. Create a function that adds the group's hierarchy to an array
2. Loop through the array of groups, and check against your permissions.

**The function**

```
function getGroupHierarchy($groupId, $cxn)
{
    $groupArray = array();

    //Push the group to the array..
    $groupArray[] = $groupId;

    //Get the parent id of this group
    $subGroupOf = mysqli_query($cxn,'SELECT subGroupOf FROM group WHERE id="'.$groupId.'"');

    //There is no parent, just return the array.
    if($subGroupOf == NULL)
    {
        return $groupArray;
    }

    //Continue checking the parent group(s).
    getGroupHierarchy($subGroupOf, $cxn);
}
```

**Calling the function, and checking against permissions:**

```
// Get group of current user
$groupId = mysqli_query($cxn,'SELECT group FROM user WHERE id='.$userID);

$allGroups = getGroupHierarchy($groupId, $cxn);

//Compare each group to permissions.
foreach($groupArray as $group)
{
    if($group == $permissions)
        return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through a recursive function that checks for the subgroup, and continues up until the "subGroupOf" id is NULL.

For example:

```
function getTopParentGroup($groupId, $cxn) {
    $subGroupOf = mysqli_query($cxn,'SELECT subGroupOf FROM group WHERE id="'.$groupId.'"');

    //There is no parent, just return the group
    if($subGroupOf == NULL)
    {
        return $group;
    }
    //A parent has been found, continue...  
    getTopParentGroup($subGroupOf, $cxn);
}
```

Comment: I know I'm being petty, but how would I go about this without using a function? Maybe with a While loop?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.  You said there is no limit to the number of groups, therefore you have to continuously loop back with different variable values each time.  You're going to have to do some sort of recursive function to loop through each group and retrieve it's parent.